# Convert C# function call to a string

Tags: c#

I would like to create a function that converts a "C# function call" to a string. 
For example:
In my C# Project there is a public function, that can be called like this:

```
myTestClass.myTestFunction();
```

It's a function without arguments and returnvalue.
Now I would like to implement another function that accepts a C#
"Expression" as argument and converts the "Expression" to a string:

```
Expression<Func<???>> expr = () => myTestClass.myTestFunction();
string myString="";
myString=convertExpressionToString(expr);
```

myString should contain now "myTestClass.myTestFunction();"
It is important that the complete function call including the class
name is inside the string.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: you might want to wait for c#6 with the `nameof()` function

Comment: I don't think there is a simple solution using the BCL,but there are some third party libraries that support printing expressions using C# syntax.

Comment: Search for "reflection" and "member expressions." This type of question has been answered here before.

Answer (score 4):

For this case you can simply write

```
private static string ConvertExpressionToString(LambdaExpression expr)
{
    var methodCallExpr = expr.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    if (methodCallExpr != null ) {
        return methodCallExpr.Method.DeclaringType.Name + "." +
            methodCallExpr.Method.Name + "();";
    }
}
```

The general case is more complicated; however, this gives you an idea of where to start.

---

A more elaborate version prints parameters passed as constant expressions:

```
private static string ConvertExpressionToString(LambdaExpression expr)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var methodCallExpr = expr.Body as MethodCallExpression;
    sb.Append(methodCallExpr.Method.DeclaringType.Name)
        .Append(".")
        .Append(methodCallExpr.Method.Name)
        .Append("(");
    var arguments = methodCallExpr.Arguments;
    for (int i = 0; i < arguments.Count; i++) {
        if (i > 0) {
            sb.Append(", ");
        }
        var constExpr = arguments[i] as ConstantExpression;
        if (constExpr == null) {
            sb.Append("<expr>");
        } else {
            sb.Append(constExpr.ToString());
        }
    }
    sb.Append(");");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

It can cope with this expression:

```
Expression<Action> expr = () => myTestClass.myTestFunction(5, "hello");
```

However, since the parameters can be any valid expressions, it quickly becomes complicated to include other cases. And then there are `out` and `ref` parameters and optional parameters.

Comment: @AT_VI_MaP, you mark a solution by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `ToString` on the method's body.

```
string myString = expr.Body.ToString();
```

Comment: That prints a string representation of the expression, but the output is not a proper C# expression. Not sure if that's acceptable to the OP.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Where does he say that the output should be a C# expression?  For the expression given he said that the output should be `myTestClass.myTestFunction();`.  This creates that result for input of that format.

Comment: hmm, just checked. It doesn't include the class name for static methods.

Answer (score 0):

what you're trying to get is an action

```
Expression<Action> expr = () => myTestClass.myTestFunction();
MethodCallExpression mbr = (MethodCallExpression)expr.Body;
String methodName = mbr.Method.Name;
Assert.AreEqual(methodName, "myTestFunction");
MemberExpression me = (MemberExpression) mbr.Object;
String memberName = me.Member.Name;
Assert.AreEqual(methodName, "myTestClass");
String finalName = string.Format("{0}.{1}()", memberName, methodName);
Assert.AreEqual("myTestClass.myTestFunction()", finalName);
```

because you're accessing myTestClass via a closure you need to realize that you're accessing it via a Member Expression
so the body is a Method call. we get the method name from that, then we get the expression representing the object that we're calling the method on, we cast that to a member expression because that's what it is in this case and we get the name from the member on that member expression.